# C function calling without required parameters

Tags: c, libuv

I've been looking at this source code provided by developers of a library called libuv.  In some of the example code they pass a function as a parameter for another function but none of the required parameters are passed. How are the parameters being filled out? The function I'm looking at is uv_fs_open.

Here is the link to the source (look around line 1000 for the function code): https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/202195c2f45ced200ccf880ff4502eee94f11ab5/src/unix/fs.c
Here is the example code:

```
int main() {
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    int r = uv_fs_open(loop, &open_req, path, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR, open_cb);

    if (r) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error at opening file: %s.\n", 
                uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
    }  

    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}

void open_cb(uv_fs_t* req) {
    int result = req->result;

    if (result == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at opening file: %s.\n", 
                uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
    }  

    uv_fs_req_cleanup(req);
    uv_fs_read(loop, &read_req, result, buf, sizeof(buf), -1, read_cb);
}
```

Comment: You know what a function pointer is, right ? It looks like the library uses function pointers to pass callback functions.

Comment: `uv_fs_open` provides the parameters when *it* calls `open_cb` , which was provided as a function pointer parameter.

Comment: Do you mean passing `open_cb` to `uv_fs_open` with no arguments? That's because  you don't supply the arguments there, you are only telling `uv_fs_open` which function to call so that *it* can supply the arguments.

Comment: Assuming you have little experience with c (by the nature of your question), you're much better off learning from actual learning material (books, tutorials, dedicated web sites) than from 1 of the more advanced pieces of code around the open source world.

Comment: @rreichel you deleted your comment, but the reason you don't see `uv_fs_open` doing anything with its argument `cb` (which was passed as `open_cb`) is that it is handled by the macro called `POST`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I do know what a function pointer is but I'm moving to C from a Java background so its been slow going and not the first thing I thought of. Thanks again!  @WeatherVane I did delete it - Accidentally added the comment too early - whoops.

Comment: 2 years and a lot more CS schooling later I just wanted to thank all of you for your kind responses - I realize this was a newbie question and really appreciate the helpful constructive responses you all gave. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libuv uses a pattern called *callback baton* for its async functions. The rationale is very simple: let's assume you want to do something asynchronously. So you pass a callback function as a [function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) to call when it's done. libuv's functions do their job asynchronously and call the function you specified when they're done.

However, if you have more than one places where you call these functions, once the callback is called, you are going to need to tell **which** request the callback is called for. That is the purpose of the *baton* object. In the case of your example code, that's the `open_req` variable (of the type `uv_fs_t`).

You can read more about libuv's file system operations [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs.html).

Comment: Thanks @Venemo ! Heres a quick follow up: Where is the documentation for writing a callback to match the uv_fs_cb type?  The API docs don't specify that

Comment: @rreichel most of the time, those callbacks accept a single parameter whose type is a pointer to the *baton* object. I suggest you take a look at the libuv book: http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/ it also has a chapter on file system operations: http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/filesystem.html